# Getting 404 error when trying to access local files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to make a very simple html with local server that displays all images in a local directory (content folder). But I am getting `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/content/ 404 (Not Found)`

So, my file structure looks like:

```
rootfolder
   -content/
   -js/
   -index.html
   -server.js
```

server.js looks like this:

```
var connect = require('connect')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server running on 8080...')
  console.log('dirname', __dirname)
})
```

index.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="img-container">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

index.js looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var folder = 'content/'

  $.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success: function (data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
            $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" )
        }
      })
    }
  })

  console.log('test2')
}
```

The code isn't very clean at the moment but I want to figure out why I am getting 404 Not Found error first.

Comment: this code doesn't really make sense.  you are trying to get a *folder*, (which isn't a file, hence the 404), then are trying to treat the folder like data, and looking for HTML elements in it?  none of this is going to work.

Comment: I'd also add to this to ask why he's using `connect`? It would make much more sense just using express imho.